# Unable to upload data using fruitstrap (iOS device). Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, appdata

I am trying to upload data to my app using fruitstrap this way.

```
./fruitstrap upload --bundle-id com.x.x --file /path/to/data-file.xcappdata/
```

but I get a "Segmentation fault: 11" error. Does anyone know why? and how it can be fixed?

and when I say.

```
./fruitstrap upload --bundle-id com.x.x --file /path/to/data-file --target / [or] /Documents/
```

I get a message saying unable to open file "/path/to/data-file.xcappdata/"

(I know I get Segmentation fault: 11 mostly when the program tries to access/manipulate memory it really can't.)

But question is has anyone seen this? And maybe fixed this?

Comment: This really isn't about programming. Probably better to ask this at a dedicated forum for that app.

Comment: It is, I plan on re-writing the tool to fit my needs. But am not sure what could be going wrong. Do I not have read/write permissions for the /Documents folder on the device? Or has anything changed with MobileDevice framework that needs to be handled? So on..